# Is there a way to apply 'Smote' in Sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to build a random forest model in Spark by using sparklyr. Since the data set is highly unbalanced, I tried using Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique ('Smote') and had a significant increase in recall value with a sample data which was extracted to R environment.

Because of the volume of my data set is huge, it is not efficient to extract data it to R environment. I have to implement my model and deal with unbalanced data in Spark. 
However 'smote'ing technique does not exist in Sparklyr package. Is there a way to deal with unbalanced datasets in sparklyr?

Comment: You may want to add some additional context on what 'smote' is